# Python tesseract installation on Mac

Tags: python, tesseract

I am trying to install [python-tesseract](http://code.google.com/p/python-tesseract/) on my mac with little success. Can someone give me a tutorial or link to one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a [tutorial](http://code.google.com/p/python-tesseract/wiki/HowToCompilePythonTesseractForMacMountainLion) for Installing the library on Mac.

Here is a [tutorial](http://code.google.com/p/python-tesseract/wiki/HowToCompilePythonTesseractForHomebrewMacMountainLion) for Installing on Mac using HomeBrew

## EDIT

Looks like the link is stale:

- Here is the updated link: [HowToCompileForHomebrewMac](http://code.google.com/p/python-tesseract/wiki/HowToCompileForHomebrewMac)
- Other compilation options can be [found here](http://code.google.com/p/python-tesseract/w/list)
- Usage can be found here: [CodeSnippets](http://code.google.com/p/python-tesseract/wiki/CodeSnippets)

Comment: Hi Karthik, I installed tesseract via Homebrew on Mac OSX, it installed fine, version 3.0.2.. Now how do I use it in Python? I tried `import tesseract`, gave import error.

Comment: See this snippet: http://code.google.com/p/python-tesseract/wiki/CodeSnippets If that does not work, please create a new question, with the stack trace.